# element inside another jquery scrollLeft

Tags: jquery

For example, I have the following code

```
<div style="width: 100px; overflow: auto;" class="slide-container">
 long content here
</div>

$(".slide-container").scroll(function (e) {
 var scrollLeftValue = $(this).scrollLeft(); /* want get scroll left count */
});
```

When I scroll content left scrollLeftValue is always 0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to set the white-space: nowrap style.... like this

```
<div style="width: 100px; overflow: auto; white-space:nowrap;" class="slide-container">
 long content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.scrollLeft(value)` gets the current horizontal position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements.

By default the current value is `0` of the horizontal scroll position.

consider this: http://jsbin.com/oqopes/1/edit

```
$("div.demo").scrollLeft(300);
       //-----------------^--------------this will scroll at 300px horizontal

 $("div.demo").scrollLeft();
       //-----------------^--------------none specified then scroll at 0 horiz
```